# How can I extract files to a different destination filename from tarfile in python?

Tags: python, tarfile

I have a `tarfile.TarFile` from which I would like to extract some files to a modified destination filename; there is an existing file with the same name as the archive member that I do not want to touch.
Specifically, I want to append a suffix, e.g. a member in the archive called `foo/bar.txt` should be extracted as `foo/bar.txt.mysuffix`.

The two somewhat obvious but also somewhat unsatisfactory approaches are:

- extract each file using `extractfile`, create renamed file and copy content using `shutil.copyfileobj`; however, this is either limited to regular files or all the special handling, e.g for sparse files, symlinks, directories etc. implemented in `tarfile` would have to be replicated.
- `extractall` to a temporary directory and then rename and copy to destination; this just feels unnecessarily convoluted, requires more interaction with the host system and introduces new failure modes, and it seems easy to get this subtly wrong (e.g. see warnings on `shutil.copy/copy2`).

Is there no interface or hook on the `TarFile` that would allow to implement this concisely and correctly?

Comment: You mentioned creating renamed file and copying contents from extracted file, but I don't understand what's wrong with just renaming the extracted file in place?

Comment: Right, sorry, that's some missing context; the reason is that there is an existing file under the destination name and I don't want to overwrite that. I'll add this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [`Lib/tarfile.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tarfile.py), I came across this [comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4134f154ae2f621f25c5d698cc0f1748035a1b88/Lib/tarfile.py#L2145-L2147):

```py
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Below are the different file methods. They are called via
    # _extract_member() when extract() is called. They can be replaced in a
    # subclass to implement other functionality.

    def makedir(self, tarinfo, targetpath):
       #...
    
    def makefile(self, tarinfo, targetpath):
       # ...
```

These methods are not mentioned in the official reference documentation, but they appear to be fair game. To overwrite these on an existing open `TarFile` instance, we can create a subclass Facade/Wrapper:

```py
class SuffixingTarFile(tarfile.TarFile):
    def __init__(self, suffix: str, wrapped: tarfile.TarFile):
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.wrapped, attr)

    def makefile(self, tarinfo, targetpath):
        super().makefile(tarinfo, targetpath + self.suffix)

    # overwrite makedir, makelink, makefifo, etc. as desired
```

Example:

```py
tar = tarfile.open(...)
star = SuffixingTarFile(".foo", tar)
star.extractall()  # extracts all (regular) file members with .foo suffix appended
```

Answer (score 0):

There is TarFile.getmembers() method which returns the members of the archive as a list.
And there you can loop and choose what files you want to extract or not.Depending on the size of your tar ,your second approach can be viable too but not the best.

```
object = tarfile.open('example.tar', 'r')
for member in object.getmembers():
    if "whatever" in member.name:
        object.extract(member, "example_dir")
```

Comment: Ok, sure, but this does not allow renaming the individual files while extracting them.

Comment: Thats a really simple os call,can you elaborate why you need there renaming?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was missing from the question; there is an existing file with the same name as the archive member, that I do not want to touch.